# Checking if given URL exists form Angular 2+

Tags: angular, cross-domain, remote-server

I was given a task to create an app that will tell which URL's are broken, out of an array of URL's. So for example for 'www.google.com' i will return 'working' and for 'www,gooogle.con' i will return 'broken'.

My first approach was to try and send GET request using HTTP Client, but the browser blocks my requests due to CORS policy. Since changing the server side code is not really an option, I was wondering is there a way to work around this?

Also, I would like to know if there is a different approach to a task in hand that would make things easier for me?

Also disabling browser security is not really an option because i have to be able to distribute the project.

Comment: If the below solution solves your problem, then could you accept it as solution?

Answer (score 0):

Let's approach it in a little different way. You have to check whether given list of URLs are working or not using Angular 2+.

You can write E2E tests in Angular. It will open the browser and will load each and every given URL automatically. After loading a URL you have to just check the response code.

---

Add below code in your `app.e2e-spec.ts` file:

```
describe('Test App', () => {
let page: AppPage;

beforeEach(() => {
  page = new AppPage();
});

function httpGet(siteUrl) {
  var http = require('http');
  var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
  http.get(siteUrl, function(response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on("data", function(chunk) {});
    response.on('end', function() {
      defer.fulfill({
        statusCode: response.statusCode
      });
    });
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    defer.reject('404');
  });

  return defer.promise;
}

describe('Checking URLS', function () {
  const urls = [
    'http://www.google.com',
    'http://www.angular.io',
    'http://www.lakjsldkjalskjdlkjalskjdlkajsldkja.com',
    'http://www.stackoverflow.com',
    'http://www.withgoogle.co.in',
    'http://www.kajshdkjhaksj.com'
  ];

  for (let url of urls) {
    it('check '+url, async function () {
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
      const elm = element(by.css("html"));
      let res = '';
      await httpGet(url).then(function(result){
        res = result['statusCode']+'';
      });
      browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 5000).then(() => {
        expect(res).not.toEqual('404');
      });
    });
  }
});
```

The above E2E test code will check each URL and if URL doesn't exists then it will throw `404` and will also show failed test. Thus, you will know which URLs are broken.

[image: Ng Test Results]